# image as header for each column in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gridview, datatable

I have a  data table which is displayed as a gridview in ASP.NET. It has a column: temperature . I want to put picture of thermometer instead of writing temperature. I want this picture only for this column and not for the whole grid view. How do i do that?

Comment: Just an off the top of my head guess atm, but if you get stumped on this, you could try setting the header text to "<img src="" />"

Comment: whats your GridView markup made up of? BoundFields, TemplateFields or are you just autogenerating them?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily in a GridView by using the `HeaderImageUrl` property on the column.

For Example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderImageUrl="icon.png" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderImageUrl="icon.png" />
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```